# Unable to start SQL server Agents

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, ado.net

been trying to configure an ADO.NET connection for my Visual Studio application but I am running into issues and having no luck at all troubleshooting them. The major error that I run into is:

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or not accessible. Verify the instance name is correct and that SQL server is configured to allow remote connections (Error 40: Could not open connection to the SQL server)*

The steps I undertook to troubleshoot this are:
1. Open up Sql server configuration manager and under the SQL Server Network Configuration, Protocols for MSSQLSERVER,SQLExpress, SQL server 2008 **connection string data source** I enable each of the protocol names (Shared memory, Named pipes,TCP/IP,VIA)

1. As instructed I stop the SQL server services first under the SQL server services nodes.
2. Now I click start, MSSQL server service starts but both SQL Server 2008 and SQLEXPRESS agents do not. Stating the following:
   *The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details*

This might just be the problem as when I attempt to create the connection string , the server name specified is MYWORLD/SQL SERVER 2008. Since the SQL server 2008 agent service refuses to start, the connection fails, leading to the first error message.

Does anybody have any leads on this and can let me know the necessary steps to mitigate this.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Browser service must be running to connect to a named instance.

Use SQL Servr Configuration Manager under Configuration Tools under Microsot SQL Server 2008 to assign the logon accounts for each service you want to run.  Do NOT use any other method to assign user accounts because the correct rights will not be enabled.

Comment: Ok this did not work for me. I did the exact same thing as stated but no success at all :(  Any further ideas? Thanks though